# Shared Workspace(TFS) in Visual Studio 2017 with using a Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, cmd

Im a trainie and learning C# at the moment and have basic knowledge about how TFS and workspaces work. 
Im using VS2017 in a VM which has access to TFS.

**Problem**

when i go in to VS2017 Source code control i can see the shared user workspace name. And when i try to use dev cmd or normal command prompt and type the `tf workspaces`, it does not show any workspace available and gives me the error `"There is no corresponding workspace found on this computer"`.

Is there anyway to see it in CMD?

**Reason**

the reason i need to test this function is that, We have a Deploy .bat/.cmd file which calls the TFS for new update, do a Realase version and then put it to a given fix directoy.

Im sorry if i cant provide more details about the problem. Company Policy.

I could try to answer any further questions.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you provide a filter such as owner, computer or workspace name, Team Foundation only displays information about the workspaces that you have created.

**Command to get workspaces on current VM:**

```
tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /server:teamserver
```

[Workspace Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.80).aspx)

**Note:**  To use the workspace command you must have the Read permission set to **Allow**.

**Word of caution:** Pulling down a release version from a bat file is normally a bad approach and can cause problems. I would recommend taking the opposite approach. Instead of running a bat file to trigger a build/deploy 
have TFS trigger the deployment and workspace update by some action or manual action in order for it to control your process. You can always use the bat file for deployment steps just have TFS setup and call it for you.